# How to clear up textarea ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I've got

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-2 img-fake"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 native-item ">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" ng-model="newComment" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && comment(existingItem,newComment)"></textarea>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

and in the `comment` function i've got

```
 $scope.comment = function(existingItem,newComment){
      existingItem.comments.push(newComment);
      $scope.newComment = '';
    } // just adding text from textarea to the list
```

so i'm wondering why the value of textarea does not go to empty value

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PuWhwPwccrlfvBdKuQCV?p=preview. Post a complete example reproducing the problem.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Yes, but you still haven't posted a complete example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Have you checked the console while comment method works? There might be an error that prevents the method work.

Comment: And your new code is invalid HTML, and doesn't use ng-model anymore: `ng-Comment"`

Comment: i've got no console errors

Comment: I've reproduced your case and it seems to work here. http://plnkr.co/edit/jgZcKPLJkRtVjXHM3p6h?p=preview
When you press Enter, the textarea is cleared. Try to check the differences if you have any.

Comment: You probably have a child scope problem and you are breaking the golden rule of always using an object in `ng-model`. Without a [mcve] all we can do is guess

Comment: i having same issue

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/kmBA3Cco8QNDL8i4eOjz its working.

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="navbar-collapse">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-2 img-fake"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 native-item ">
          {{newComment}}
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" ng-model="newComment" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && comment(existingItem, newComment)"></textarea>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

In youe case it is not working because, you may not define `comment` property of `existingItem`

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.newComment = 'asdf';
    $scope.existingItem = {};
    $scope.existingItem.comments = [];

 $scope.comment = function(existingItem, newComment){
   existingItem.comments.push(newComment);
   console.log(existingItem.comments);
      $scope.newComment = '';
    } 
});
```

Comment: i've got ng-model="newComment" in ng-repeat module(maybe this is because of that?). I did what you wrote above and it still a value in textarea

Comment: See the plunker I linked and will please add that code?

Comment: i've got no permission to your jsfiddle 
but try to put for example `<div class="col-lg-10 native-item " ng-repeat="one in [1,2,3,4]">` instead of `<div class="col-lg-10 native-item " ">`

Comment: and when you will clear up `$scope.newComment = '';` it will not work.So that what i wanted to point on

Comment: because i've got the same story

Comment: i've putted ng-model="existingItem.newComment" to bind this comment to concrete item comment, so it worked. i've realised own mistake, because i wanted to clear up scope variable that has multiple declarations all over html because of ng-repeat module . So tnx )

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue and fixed like this

```
$scope.comment = function(existingItem,newComment){
    existingItem.comments.push(newComment);
    $scope.newComment = 'xx'; // add a random data
    $scope.$evalAsync(function() { $scope.newComment  = '' ; }); //or  use $timeout(function() { $scope.newComment  = '' ; });
}
```